# Stuck when using currentThread as the lock object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I tried to simulate this scene: thread in an array can execute one after another as the order in the array. My idea is to let `thread[i]` always notify `thread[(i+1)%threads.length]`.

However, the code will be stuck somewhere:

```
    public class OrderedOperationThreadOneLock {

    //<- Assign tasks to workers
    private static final String[] message1 = {"A", "D", "G"};
    private static final String[] message2 = {"B", "E", "H"};
    private static final String[] message3 = {"C", "F", "I"};

    private static final Task task1 = new Task(message1);
    private static final Task task2 = new Task(message2);
    private static final Task task3 = new Task(message3);

    private static Thread[] workers = {
            new Thread(task1),
            new Thread(task2),
            new Thread(task3)
    }; //->

    private static void printThreadsStatus() {
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + workers[i].getName() +
                    "\tPriority: " + workers[i].getPriority() +
                    "\tStatus: " + workers[i].getState()
            );
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    }


    // Print a message then wait for other thread notify.
    // Until all the messages are outputted.
    private static class Task implements Runnable {
        private final String[] messages;
        Task(String[] messages) {
            this.messages = Arrays.copyOf(messages, messages.length);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) {
                System.out.println(messages[i]);
                Thread curThread = Thread.currentThread();

                // Stuck here
                synchronized (curThread) {
                    try {
                        curThread.wait();
                        printThreadsStatus();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.err.println("Oh, Why?");
                    }
                }
                wakeUpNext();
            }
        }

        // `thread[i]` always notify `thread[(i+1)%threads.length]`
        private void wakeUpNext() {
            Thread curThread = Thread.currentThread();
            int i = 0;
            boolean isNotified = false;
            while (i < workers.length && !isNotified) {
                if (curThread.getId() == workers[i].getId()) {
                    int toNotify = (i+1) % workers.length;
                    System.out.println("Worker " + i + " is waking up " + toNotify);
                    synchronized (workers[toNotify]) {
                        workers[toNotify].notify();
                    }
                    isNotified = true;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; ++i) {
            workers[i].start();
            Thread.sleep(10); // Ensure start in 1,2,3 sequence
        }

        System.out.println("================================");
        printThreadsStatus();
        synchronized (workers[0]) {
            workers[0].notify();
            printThreadsStatus();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; ++i) {
            workers[i].join(5000);
            printThreadsStatus(); // All the threads are in WAITING status...
        }

        printThreadsStatus();
    }
}
```

However, if I use the `Task` as the monitor lock. Then the program won't be stuck:

```
public class OrderedOperationThreadSingleLock {
    //<- Assign tasks to workers
    private static final String[] message1 = {"A", "D", "G"};
    private static final String[] message2 = {"B", "E", "H"};
    private static final String[] message3 = {"C", "F", "I"};

    private static final Task[] tasks = {
            new Task(message1),
            new Task(message2),
            new Task(message3)
    };

    private static Thread[] workers = {
            new Thread(tasks[0]),
            new Thread(tasks[1]),
            new Thread(tasks[2])
    };//->

    private static void printThreadsStatus() {
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + workers[i].getName() +
                    "\tPriority: " + workers[i].getPriority() +
                    "\tStatus: " + workers[i].getState()
            );
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    }


    private static class Task implements Runnable {
        private final String[] messages;
        Task(String[] messages) {
            this.messages = Arrays.copyOf(messages, messages.length);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) {
                System.out.println(messages[i]);
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                        printThreadsStatus();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.err.println("Oh, Why?");
                    }
                }
                wakeUpNext();
            }
        }

        // Use task as the lock instead of thread object
        private void wakeUpNext() {
            int i = 0;
            boolean isNotified = false;
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            while (i < workers.length && !isNotified) {
                if (t.getId() == workers[i].getId()) {
                    int toNotify = (i+1) % workers.length;
                    System.out.println("Worker " + i + " is waking up " + toNotify);
                    synchronized (tasks[toNotify]) {
                        System.out.println("Prepare Waking up " + toNotify);
                        tasks[toNotify].notify();
                    }
                    isNotified = true;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; ++i) {
            workers[i].start();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        System.out.println("================================");
        printThreadsStatus();
        synchronized (tasks[0]) {
            tasks[0].notify();
            printThreadsStatus();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; ++i) {
            workers[i].join(5000);
            printThreadsStatus();
        }

        printThreadsStatus();
    }
}
```

My question is why thread object would block the executing and task won't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing is that problem is in `workers[i].join(5000);`. Method `join` is synchronized on thread too and invoke `wait`, so when you notify thread in `wakeUpNext` you wake up wrong one.

It happens next way.

- Main thread notify thread 1
- Thread 1 wake up
- Thread 1 notify thread 2
- Thread 1 sleep waiting thread 1 to by notified.
- Main thread invoke `join` on thread 1 which lead to main thread sleep to.
- At some point thread 3 notify thread 1, but there is two thread waiting this notification (Thread 1 itself and main thread) for some reason main thread get notified.
- Main thread get back to sleep because `join` method ready to spurious wake ups

Comment: That is a possible cause, though only if all the threads have finished and I suspect they don't get that far.

Comment: I'll add scenario to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario which may cause a problem is like this.

- Thread 1 notify thread 2
- Thread 2 wake up and notify thread 3
- Thread 3 wake up and notify thread 1 (Notification is lost because thread 1 is not slipping yet)
- Thread 1 goes to sleep (and sleep forever)